# Split browserify bundled files on some others, keeping dependencies among them

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

The "main.js" file of my application has grown up so much, so i want to find a way of split it on some other different files, 
to avoid have only one huge file which delays a lot the first load of my page.

I currently do a release of one bundle file => main.js which contains a lot of modules whose interact with each.

I want to split/trasnform this:

```
            - main.js ===> - global.js
                           - a.js
                           - b.js
                           - c.js
```

So, for my three webpages i would like to load the scripts like that:

```
//Page A
<script src="global.js">
<script src="a.js">

//Page B
<script src="global.js">
<script src="b.js">

//Page C
<script src="global.js">
<script src="c.js">
```

- This four bundles splitted will contain as now, dependencies between
  other modules within, which is not a big deal, and could be resolved
  using require inside each one.
- [a, b, c] hasn't module dependencies between them.
- The problem is that [a,b,c] containes modules with dependencies on [global]... and i don't know how manage the situation.

This is the a little example of what happens:

global.js

```
//[module_global1]
  var mod = {};
  (...)
  module.exports = mod;


//[module_global2]
  var mod = {}; 
  var module_global1 = require("./module_global1");

  //(...)
  module.exports = mod;
```

a.js

```
//[module_a1]
  var mod = {};
  (...)
  module.exports = mod;


//[module_a2]
  var mod = {}; 
  var module_a1 = require("./module_a1");

  //HERE => How?
  var module_global1 = require("./module_global1");

  //(...)
  module.exports = mod;
```

b.js

```
//[module_b1]
  var mod = {};
  (...)
  module.exports = mod;


//[module_b2]
  var mod = {}; 
  var module_b1 = require("./module_b1");

  //(...)
  module.exports = mod;

//[module_b3]
  var mod = {}; 
  var module_b1 = require("./module_b1");
  var module_b2 = require("./module_b2");

  //HERE => How?
  var module_global2 = require("./module_global2");

  //(...)
  module.exports = mod;
```

c.js

```
//[module_c1]
  var mod = {};

  //HERE => How?
  var module_b2 = require("./module_b2");

  (...)
  module.exports = mod;
```

I think this could be easily solved bundling [global] on [a,b,c] for each one, having then [global-a, global-b, global-c].

But indeed, the most part of the code is inside global, so global wouldn't be cached when it will being loaded the first time on the page and it will pay the load time on the page.

I don't shuffle to have the varables of [global] as global variables either.

What can i do? Maybe merge with AMD or something similar?

Comment: you seems to need the factor-bundle to make such setup work: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#factor-bundle

Comment: @Sombriks Well. I think the stuff is more complicated than that. The clobal module, will have classes which depends or themselves and then communicate with the other modules. So what i will  need is a scope which wraps the global and a or b or c for each webpage, and i dont want to repeat the code loading of something what i have already loaded. Anybody understand my approach?